# WebView .reload() not working properly on iOS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm using React Native's WebView component to display a chart. The chart has time scale selection controls and these are passed as props to the component containing the WebView. When a new time scale is passed to it, I need to reload the injected JS so that a new chart is rendered with the newly selected time scale. Here is the component:

```
function CandleChart(timeScale) {
  const width = Dimensions.get('window').width;
  const [candleChartJS, setCandleChartJS] = useState(
    chartJS.candleChart(width, timeScale.timeScale)
  );
  const [currTimeScale, setCurrTimeScale] = useState('1h');

  useEffect(() => {
    setCandleChartJS(chartJS.candleChart(width, timeScale.timeScale));
    if (currTimeScale !== timeScale.timeScale) {
      CandleWebViewRef.reload();
      setCurrTimeScale(timeScale.timeScale);
    }
  }, [timeScale]);

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, height: 300, zIndex: -1 }}>
      <WebView
        ref={CandleWVref => (CandleWebViewRef = CandleWVref)}
        originWhitelist={['*']}
        useWebKit={true}
        source={{ html: candleChartHtml }}
        domStorageEnabled={true}
        javaScriptEnabled={true}
        style={styles.WebViewStyle}
        injectedJavaScript={candleChartJS}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Calling .reload() inside the `useEffect()` function works just as expected on Android, but on iOS the WebView just keeps loading after a different time scale is selected. How can I achieve the same behavior on iOS?

Edit: I've solved my issue thanks to Mayank Garg, I'll just post the slightly modified final component here because his answer is aimed at class-based components, and I'm using functional components and hooks:

```
function CandleChart(timeScale) {
  const width = Dimensions.get('window').width;
  const [candleChartJS, setCandleChartJS] = useState(
    chartJS.candleChart(width, timeScale.timeScale)
  );
  const [currTimeScale, setCurrTimeScale] = useState('1h');
  const [isReloadWebView, setReloadWebView] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setCandleChartJS(chartJS.candleChart(width, timeScale.timeScale));
    if (currTimeScale !== timeScale.timeScale) {
      setReloadWebView(!isReloadWebView);
      setCurrTimeScale(timeScale.timeScale);
    }
  }, [timeScale]);

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, height: 300, zIndex: -1 }}>
      <WebView
        ref={CandleWVref => (CandleWebViewRef = CandleWVref)}
        key={isReloadWebView}
        originWhitelist={['*']}
        useWebKit={true}
        source={{ html: candleChartHtml }}
        domStorageEnabled={true}
        javaScriptEnabled={true}
        style={styles.WebViewStyle}
        injectedJavaScript={candleChartJS}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use add a key in key params in webview
this.state={
isRelaodWebview:false
}

```
return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, height: 300, zIndex: -1 }}>
      <WebView
        ref={CandleWVref => (CandleWebViewRef = CandleWVref)}
        originWhitelist={['*']}
        useWebKit={true}
        source={{ html: candleChartHtml }}
        key={this.state.isRelaodWebview} ------ add this line
        domStorageEnabled={true}
        javaScriptEnabled={true}
        style={styles.WebViewStyle}
        injectedJavaScript={candleChartJS}
      />
    </View>
  );
```

in useeffect block

```
useEffect(() => {
    setCandleChartJS(chartJS.candleChart(width, timeScale.timeScale));
    if (currTimeScale !== timeScale.timeScale) {
      //CandleWebViewRef.reload();
      this.setState({isRelaodWebview:!this.state.isRelaodWebview}) ----- addd this line
      setCurrTimeScale(timeScale.timeScale);
    }
  }, [timeScale]);
```

that will help you, it helps me

Comment: Thank you, this works great on both platforms. I just had to modify the code a bit because your solution is for class-based components and I'm using functional components and hooks. I'll edit my original answer with the final component for anyone who might be looking for a functional component solution to a similar problem. Do you mind explaining how and why this works? Why does changing the key property cause the WebView to re-render?